# Relational Database: Items whose Properties depend on Context

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am trying to set up a database, but I am somewhat lost as to how to structure it. It seems to make sense to make it relational, since in my Database `Objects` hold lists of `atoms`, and those atoms can reoccur in other `Object` items. So we have

`Object` Pseudocode:

```
{
  name: 'object1',
  atoms: [ 
    {name: 'atom1', color: 'red'}, 
    {name: 'atom2', color: 'green'}, 
  ...
  ]
}
```

What I struggle with is this: **Atoms have different colors, depending on what object they appear in.** So `atom1` might be *red* in `object1`, but *green* in `object2`. Their color depends on the overall context and what other atoms are present in the object. But they are not conceptually distinct atoms because of that -it still makes sense to say `atom1` is sometimes green, sometimes red. I still want to be able to count them as such.

I don't understand how I best model this onto a relational database. Atoms reoccur in Objects, but some of their properties might be different. So I can't simply say to `Object1` to just look up `atom1, atom2, & atom3` from the atoms TABLE. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like three tables:

`objects`

- `objectId`
- `objectName`

`atoms`

- `atomId`
- `atomName`

`objectAtoms`

- `objectId`
- `atomId`
- `color`

I'm not sure if "color" should be a separate reference table as well.

Comment: missing the objects.objectName. Personally I prefer objects.name / atoms.name, otherwise it looks like we are repeating the entity name in each column...

Answer (score 0):

Bit verbose, but shows the underlying design methodology: predicates and constraints in natural language.

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

[p x]   = predicate  x
(c x.y) = constraint x.y

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

---

**[p 1]** Object identified by `OBJECT_ID`, named `OBJECT_NAME` exists.

*(c 1.1)* Object is identified by  `OBJECT_ID`.

*(c 1.2)* Each object has exactly one name; for each name, exactly one object has that name.

```
object {OBJECT_ID, OBJECT_NAME} -- p 1
    PK {OBJECT_ID}              -- c 1.1
    AK {OBJECT_NAME}            -- c 1.2
```

**[p 2]** Atom identified by `ATOM_NAME` exists.

*(c 2.1)* Atom is identified by atom name.

```
atom {ATOM_NAME}  -- p 2
  PK {ATOM_NAME}  -- c 2.1
```

**[p 3]** Atom color `ATOM_COLOR` exists.

*(c 3.1)* Atom color is identified by `ATOM_COLOR`.

```
atom_color {ATOM_COLOR}  -- p 3
        PK {ATOM_COLOR}  -- c 3.1
```

**[p 4]** Atom `ATOM_NAME` appears in object `OBJECT_ID` in color `ATOM_COLOR`.

*(c 4.1)* For each atom appearing in an object; that atom appearing in that object appears in exactly one atom color.

*(c 4.2)* For each atom appearing in a color; that atom may appear in that color in more than one object.

*(c 4.3)* For each object and atom color; more than one atom may appear in that object in that color.

*(c 4.4)* If an atom appears in an object in a color, then that atom must exist.

*(c 4.5)* If an atom appears in an object in a color, then that object must exist.

*(c 4.6)* If an atom appears in an object in a color, then that atom color must exist.

```
atom_object {ATOM_NAME, OBJECT_ID, ATOM_COLOR}  -- p 4
         PK {ATOM_NAME, OBJECT_ID}              -- c 4.1, 4.2, 4.3

FK1 {ATOM_NAME}  REFERENCES atom       {ATOM_NAME}  -- c 4.4
FK2 {OBJECT_ID}  REFERENCES object     {OBJECT_ID}  -- c 4.5
FK3 {ATOM_COLOR} REFERENCES atom_color {ATOM_COLOR} -- c 4.6
```